# How to get an access token to pull comment author data into Integromat for posts in a Facebook group I own

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, make.com

I am trying to set-up a scenario in Integromat that reads comments on a facebook posts in a private group I own. Currently integromat can only pull comment level data, and not comment author data. However, from what I've read when integromat has been given a User Access Token from a facebook user that is an admin of the group then they can read comment author data.

Can I simply create a plain app, make it live, install it on the group, and then provide integromat my client access token from that app in order for them to be able to pull comment author data?

Comment: No, you will have to get your app reviewed first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-GROUPS_ACCESS

Comment: Once I've had the app reviewed, will supplying my user customer token to integromat allow them to pull comment author data using the API?

Comment: Once you got the permission `groups_access_member_info` reviewed as well,  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-groups_access_member_info

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like the "watch comments" module in Integromat doesn't return author data. It appears what you're trying to do is currently not possible with the "watch comments" module. Here's some data a scenario I ran returned:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "object": {},
    "parent": {},
    "message": "",
    "attachment": {
        "description": "",
        "type": "",
        "title": "",
        "target": {
            "id": "",
            "url": ""
        },
        "url": "",
        "media": {
            "image": {
                "height": ,
                "src": "",
                "width":
            }
        }
    },
    "like_count": ,
    "created_time": "",
    "comment_count": 
}
```

Comment: can you share the code you used to get this? that way many people in the future can benefit from this

Comment: It's not code - it's from a module inside Integromat :) You do it by downloading the output after a successful run of the module.